# hide/unhide button or outlets in Xcode using a single tap gesture

Tags: xcode, hide, show, uitapgesturerecognizer

this is my first time asking for some help here although I've been lurking on this forum for the past 6 months. so here a simple one and I know its been asked like many times before but none of them comes with a simple answer that really helped. hope that maybe someone here who kindly enough can help me and many others that need this with a helpful tips.

so this is what I already did to hide the outlets :

**in the header file :**

```
@interface tapgestureViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
IBOutlet UITextView *text;

}

-(IBAction)hideOutlets;

@end
```

**and on the implementation file :**

```
-(IBAction)hideOutlets:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)singleTap {

btn1.hidden = YES;
btn2.hidden = YES;
text.hidden = YES;

}
```

my simple question is : how to unhide/show the outlets again if the user tap again on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simplest way to accomplish this is by using:

```
-(IBAction)hideOutlets:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)singleTap 
{
    btn1.hidden = !btn1.hidden;
    btn2.hidden = !btn2.hidden;
    text.hidden = !text.hidden;
}
```

This will simply negate your current bool state and you're done :)

EDIT:
To check if the touch was somewhere on the form but not on the buttons or text field try using this. It should work. No need to use the `UITapGestureRecognizer`anymore.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    if (!(CGRectContainsPoint(btn1.frame, loc) || CGRectContainsPoint(btn2.frame, loc) || CGRectContainsPoint(text.frame, loc)))
    {
        btn1.hidden = !btn1.hidden;
        btn2.hidden = !btn2.hidden;
        text.hidden = !text.hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: million thanks for this simple answer and its really easy to understand. I've seen this code few days ago but its so silly that i think it won't work, well I'm happy now. thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry but some error occur here when i click on the button all the other outlets also hidden even when i already put some action to that button(to change to another view) its just keep hide/unhide and doesn't give respons to another assign syntax.please help :(

Comment: hello majster, thanks again for the another workaround. but it seems the latest code just won't work on my application since i have many other outlets on screen(uiview,uiscrollview,uialert,etc) actually i preferred the first code because its simple and more understandable. any other way you can make the first code to work? coz i really just want to hide/unhide the outlets without interfere with the outlets itself.

Comment: No, `UITapGestureRecognizer` will call your hide/show method every time you tap somewhere. The only thing that you can do to improve it to set it to a double/triple/... tap. So that if you will want to hide/show your outlets you will have to double/triple... tap on the screen. That will make your buttons "clickable". To do this set the `numberOfTapsRequired = x` property. If this is not good enough we'll try another way :)

Comment: yes, set the minimum of taps required to 2 does the trick and i think it'll do just fine for now. i think I'm ok with this method for now. but I've seen some application on the appstore that can do the single tap without affect the other buttons on screen. ex : bible+ by olive tree . so anytime you find the answer for this ill be happy to learn from you. thanks again.